# Installing a stud wall without connecting to ceiling?

Tags: walls

what is the best approach to installing a stud wall (making walk in wardrobe) without also screwing into the ceiling? I am going to pull back the carpet and nail into the floor but I am wondering if I can secure by another means instead of going into the ceiling as well. Thanks

Comment: Why would you not want to connect to the ceiling? Are you not running the walls all the way to the ceiling?

Comment: I've built display walls in a retail space, and if you build a stud wall with sheetrock or other sheathing on both sides, it will be fairly stiff with no attachment to the ceiling.  Of course it depends on how long the wall is.  What dimensions?

Comment: Indeed, how big? A single wall, or multiple at right-angles? What sort of doors?

Comment: I build walls like this tilt them up and nail into the truss or rafters from below.  It's not structural but if you plan on clothing racks or hanging things off the walls you will want to anchor the top and it can be done without going in the attic.

Comment: Thanks for the comments all, the reason for not wanting to go into the ceiling is that the beams in the ceiling run parallel to the stud wall so for me to nail it to them I would have to place the stud wall in a different position. If they ran across the stud wall I wouldn't have an issue.

Comment: The dimensions would roughly be 93 Inches height to the ceiling, 85 inches in for the longest length and 30 inches for the "L" length

Comment: So put a few pieces bridging the beams and nail to them. We agree this doesn't have to be structural...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often walls in office buildings do not extend to the roof or floor above. (Suspended ceilings are installed in the offices.)

If the room is about 12’ or so with a double top plate, it probably doesn’t need to be braced. If it’s over 12’ or so, I’d add a 2x4 brace from the top of the wall up to the floor above.

Answer (score 1):

If your walk in wardrobe has any corners or clothing racks spanning wall to wall, you will be fine if carefully constructed. Think about a backyard fence. Where the side fence meets the back fence, you have a very sturdy intersection. Another example is to think about a square/rectangular shaped room with no ceiling in the middle bigger room. You wouldn't even have to fasten it down for it to be relatively stable.

Comment: The stud wall will be an L shape with a 90 degree corner going against a side and back wall. I was thinking about connecting it to the floor and the side walls. Would this be a good option?

Comment: An L shape, with 6 corner, fastened to the floor and along 2 walls? The finished product should be very strong. Thumbs up!

Comment: @ORStudios, Agree that an L shape takes away a lot of the stability concerns.  Still wish you would give the dimensions that a few people asked about.

Comment: Hi the dimensions would roughly be 93 Inches height to the ceiling, 85 inches in for the longest length and 30 inches for the "L" length.